# Получение прогресса загрузки при отправке через POST

Tags: swift, post, swiftui, alamofire

Сделал отправку фото на сервер через `POST` запрос. Как мне корректно отобразить процесс загрузки в процентах на кнопке в мобильном приложении? В классе `ShareController` вывожу статус отправки через `print(uploadProgress)` и всё хорошо. Но при передаче на кнопку выводится только `0`.

`ShareController`:

```
class ShareController {

    public var dataResponse: String = ""
    public var loaded: Bool = false

    private var message: String
    private var user: String
    private var email: String
    private var photo: [String]
    private var video: [String]

    init(message: String, user: String, email: String, photo: [String], video: [String]) {
        self.message = message
        self.user = user
        self.email = email
        self.photo = photo
        self.video = video
    }

    func send(completion: @escaping((String) -> Void)) {
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(Data(self.message.utf8), withName: "message")
            multipartFormData.append(Data(self.user.utf8), withName: "user")
            multipartFormData.append(Data(self.email.utf8), withName: "email")
            multipartFormData.append(Data(self.photo.joined(separator: "|||").utf8), withName: "photo")
            multipartFormData.append(Data(self.video.joined(separator: "|||").utf8), withName: "video")
        }, to: "https://example.com/api/shareNews")
        .uploadProgress { progress in
            let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(1))
            let uploadProgress: Int = Int(((progress.fractionCompleted * divisor).rounded() / divisor) * 100)
            self.dataResponse = String(uploadProgress)
            print(uploadProgress)
        }
        .responseData { (data) in
            let json = try! JSON(data: data.data!)
            if !json.isEmpty {
                self.loaded = true
                completion(self.dataResponse)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Отображение кнопки и клик по ней в `ShareDataView.swift`. Там кода очень много, поэтому скопировал лишь то, что относится конкретно к кнопке:

```
@State private var sendButtonTitle: String = "Отправить"

...

Button(action: {
    self.sendButtonTitle = "Отправка... \(self.selectionUploadingStatus)%"
    self.sendButtonActive = false

    ...

    let shareController: ShareController = ShareController(message: validateForm.content, user: validateForm.user, email: validateForm.email, photo: self.preparedPhoto, video: self.preparedVideo)

    shareController.send { (dataResponse) in
        self.selectionUploadingStatus = dataResponse
        ...
        self.sendButtonTitle = "Отправить"
    }

}, label: {
    Text(self.sendButtonTitle)
})
```

Где ошибка?

Я получаю статус об успешной отправке через `completion(self.dataResponse)` в `responseData`.

Прогресс отправки приходит через `uploadProgress`. Как отправить её в кнопку?

Comment: Нужно отправку выполнять в background, а изменения на кнопке показывать в main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример отправки с прогрессом, здесь использованы 2 замыкания - для прогресса и для получения ответа по окончании загрузки

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

class ShareController {
    
    private var photo: Data
    
    init(photo: Data) {
        self.photo = photo
    }
    
    func send(onProgress: @escaping (Int) -> Void, onResponse: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        // https://code.google.com/archive/p/imageshackapi/wikis/ImageshackAPI.wiki
        let apiKey = "FPZ6EBSA3c8aaa2194e5e531ec0f55b1745c36f4"
        let url = "https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"
        
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(self.photo, withName: "fileupload", fileName: "test image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            multipartFormData.append(apiKey.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "key")
            multipartFormData.append("json".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "format")
        }, to: url)
            .uploadProgress { progress in
                let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(1))
                let uploadProgress = Int(((progress.fractionCompleted * divisor).rounded() / divisor) * 100)
                print(uploadProgress)
                onProgress(uploadProgress)
            }
            .responseData { response in
                guard
                    let data = response.data,
                    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                        onResponse("No data")
                        return
                    }
                
                onResponse(dataString)
            }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var buttonTitle = "Отправить"
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonTitle) {
            let image = UIImage(named: "pauk")!
            let shareController = ShareController(photo: image.pngData()!)
            
            shareController.send(onProgress: { progress in
                buttonTitle = "Отправка... \(progress)"
            }, onResponse: { response in
                print(response)
                buttonTitle = "Отправить"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Переделал код под свой и заработало!